# Unable to Install CME and TTM on port 80

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager, powershell

We are Installing CMS and Topology using PowerShell scripts.

In our installation scenario we have two servers in a load balanced configuration.When we run the CMS installer both in the GUI and as a script we get the same behaviour.Installing both CMS and Topology on port 80 with Host headers for the load balanced endpoints cms.dev.domain.com and topology.dev.domain.com

> The specified configuration conflicts with another application or Web
>   site configured on this machine. Select a different IP address, port
>   number or host header.

I tried with 3-4 different ports nothing worked.

Before that error occurs below message displayed

> Setting string variable 'WEB_INFOS_SHARED' to value '3:SDL Web
>   Topology Manager:(All Unassigned):topology.dev.domain.com:82'

Try to resolve the above issue using the below SDL Community Article Nothing worked.

https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=Unable-to-install-the-CME-and-Topology-Manager-websites-in-the-same-port-in-SDL-Web-8

Appreciate your help

Comment: Can you explain why you want to have CMS website and Topology Manager service on the same port?

Comment: As per client They discouraged to use other ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When CM Servers are on load balanced configurations by following below approach we resolved our issue.

1. Insert the host headers into each servers hosts file on the localhost loopback address 127.0.0.1 as shown below:
   127.0.0.1 cms.dev.domain.com
   127.0.0.1 topology.dev.domain.com
2. Save & Close Host File
3. Run the SDL CMS installer
4. Remove the host headers from each servers hosts file